# JSDoc: Lookup tutorials from different directories

Tags: jsdoc

Is there a way to ask `JSDoc` (either in the command line or through grunt-jsdoc plugin) to lookup tutorials from different directories ?

As per the [documentation](http://usejsdoc.org/about-commandline.html), `-u` allows to specify the `Directory in which JSDoc should search for tutorials.` (it says the `Directory` instead of `Directories`).

I tried the following with no luck:

- specify different strings separated by `space` or `comma`
- specify one string with shell/ant regular expression

Comment: what about putting all directories into single on ( by symlinks for example ) and pass this directory as param?

Comment: @Vasil: Yes, that is a solution that should work. Do I have to understand from your reply that, indeed, JSDoc doesn't offer a solution for my need and, as such, an external workaround should be used?

Comment: as i understand after reviewing documentation - yes. One directory per command

Comment: Too bad. Please put your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Just remember that JSDoc will consider only files contained with the specified directory. Sub-directories will not be considered. Hence, the link should be for the files not the directories.

Comment: If problem not solved - no answer )) I suggest to write simple script which will be collect all file names in list of directories and creates symlinks -but i hope you'll find better way. Please keep us in course ( if you'll find - publish answer) Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by `@Vasil Vanchuk`, a solution would be creating links to all tutorial files within a single directory. As such, JSDoc3 will be happy and it will proceed with the generation of all tutorials.

Creating/maintaining links manually would be a tedious task. Hence, and for people using `grunt`, the `grunt-contrib-symlink` come in handy. Using this plugin, the solution is reduced to a config task.

My Gruntfile.js looks like the following:

```
clean:['tmp', 'doc'],

symlink: {
    options: {
        overwrite: false,
    },
    tutorials: {
        files: [{
            cwd: '../module1/src/main/js/tut',
            dest: 'tmp/tutorial-generation-workspace',
            expand: true,
            src: ['*'],
        }, {
            cwd: '../module2/src/main/js/tut',
            dest: 'tmp/tutorial-generation-workspace',
            expand: true,
            src: ['*'],
        }]
    }
},

jsdoc: {
    all: {
        src: [
            '../module1/src/main/js/**/*.js',
            '../module2/src/main/js/**/*.js',
            './README.md',
        ],
        options: {
            destination: 'doc',
            tutorials: 'tmp/tutorial-generation-workspace',
            configure : "jsdocconf.json",
            template: 'node_modules/grunt-jsdoc/node_modules/ink-docstrap/template',
        },
    }
},

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-symlink');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jsdoc');

grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean', 'symlink', 'jsdoc']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['build']);
```

Integrating new module is translated by updating `symlink` and `jsdoc` tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just copy the files instead of linking to a bunch of directories.

E.g. create a dir in your project for documentation in which you'll copy over all relevant tutorials from where ever.

Then, in your npm scripts you can have something like this:

```
"copy:curry": "cp node_modules/@justinc/jsdocs/tutorials/curry.md doc/tutorials",
"predocs": "npm run copy:curry",
```

The `docs` script (not shown) runs `jsdoc`. `predocs` runs automatically before `docs` and, in this case copies over a tutorial in one of my packages over to `doc/tutorials`. You can then pass `doc/tutorials` as the single directory housing all your tutorials.

In `predocs` you can keep adding things to copy with `bash`'s `&&` - or if that's not available for whatever reason, you'll find npm packages which let you do this (therefore not relying on whatever shell you're using).

Now that I think about it, it's best to also delete `doc/tutorials` in `predocs`:

```
"predocs": "rm -rf doc/tutorials && mkdir -p doc/tutorials && npm run copy:tutorials",
```

That way any tutorials you once copied there (but are now not interested in) will be cleared each time you generate the docs.

btw, I opened an issue for this: https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1330